# Is there a way to make text overflow while in javascript or p5.js?

Tags: javascript, overflow, p5.js

I'm trying to make text overflow when you resize a window, like pretty much every site does. However, I have zero experience with HTML and CSS, so I only have JavaScript (I'm using the p5 library) to work with. Does anyone know if there's a way for me to do one of two things:

---

Make the text overflow somehow

Learn HTML and CSS (is there a good tutorial out there?)

---

Or should I just change it so that a certain window size changes the text manually in the code from "Example Text" to "Example\nText"? Basically, is there some function I should know about, should I do it manually, or is there a good tutorial for beginner to advanced HTML/CSS? I realize that I'm basically asking for a tutorial online, but I'm also hoping there's some other way. Help!!! :P

Comment: Based on your accepting the answer below it sounds like when you say "make text overflow" you are misusing the word "overflow" and instead mean "make text wrap." Text that "overflows" is text that is visible outside of the bounds of it's container. Text that wraps is broken into multiple lines so that it fits within the width of the container (text that wraps to fit a container horizontally could also overflow outside of that container vertically). Could you please clarify your question so that you are using the right terminology? otherwise this is a -1/close vote for confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean Text-wrap which wraps your text content inside the div element?

TLDR; Use word-wrap or overflow-wrap.
[Check this out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Text/Wrapping_Text)

Also, check out this tutorial from FreeCodeCamp. You can learn pretty much all the basics from their website itself. [HTML & Css](https://youtu.be/kMT54MPz9oE)

Comment: I did sort of mean that, I'm trying to use no html though. Is there any way to make text with javascript using the p5 library that can overflow - is there a property or something? Thanks for the tutorial, I'll use it no matter what - I need it

Comment: Looks like they have p5.js has textWrap function. Try it. https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/5081